# What does SHIMVIEW: shiminfo means?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, gdb

What does warning:

```
SHIMVIEW: ShimInfo(Complete)
```

signifies in gdb?

Using gcc 4.6.2 and gdb 7.4 on win8 32bit.

Comment: Might this help: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/41315

Comment: Or here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/7d585c05-0b61-45e7-b554-740382ffb7cc/win7-app-compat-faq-for-developers?forum=windowscompatibility#FAQ23

Answer (score 1):

SHIMVIEW messages are generated by the the Windows Compatibility subsystem e.g. if a process is configured to run in XP compatibility mode or one of the many other compatibility settings.

This message you are seeing is not necessarily relevant to the project you are working on - it could just be gdb displaying a debug message from some other process which has compatibility mode activated.

If it concerns you and you really want to know which process is doing it, use [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx), turn on PID display, and watch which process ID is printing the message.

Comment: strange, I see Windows Explorer printing it (via DebugView and checking the process id) on Win8.1. Guess it is some context-menu related or similar DLL that may be forcing Windows Explorer to run in compatibility mode. Sounds like fail design this kind of extensibility

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove it, change your platform toolset from "Visual Studio 2012 (v110)" to "Visual Studio 2012 - Windows XP (v110_xp)". I don't know how to do that for GCC, but in Visual Studio it can be done in Project Settings => Configuration Properties => General => Platform Toolset